# How to refresh a webpage with devtool JS modifications?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, page-refresh

I more or less accidentally stumbled upon a JS file with the first line reading `debug=false`. I got curious and wondered how I can reload the website with `debug=true`.

So far I've found [Chrome Workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces). It supposedly lets you save files and *"you can view them as if they were being served"*. 
I've copied and mapped the JS file to a local version but to no avail.

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure about chrome workspaces... but a tool I use to do this exact thing is Switcheroo Redirector: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg?hl=en

Comment: Thanks but that seems more useful for switching between production and dev code on a server. I'd like to make some quick edits in devtools and then just run them without too much hassle.

Comment: I just tried using chrome workspaces and I'm not having much luck with it either... it seems to ignore my local file even though I can break in it and watch the modified code run. It still uses the server side code anyway. Let me know if you figure this out because setting up a local server just to use switcheroo redirector is kind of a pain.

Comment: If I come across a solution I'll try to remember ;)

Comment: You cannot "patch" the server code using your local JS resources. For the workspaces to have this effect, a workspace folder should point to a directory in your docroot (effectively served by your HTTP server.)